# Linux shell kill command while still running based on output

Tags: linux, parsing, shell, output, terminate

I have a set of C++ projects in Code::Blocks and a script that builds all of them. The script looks as following:

```
codeblocks --build --target="release32" project1.cbp
codeblocks --build --target="release32" project2.cbp
codeblocks --build --target="release32" project3.cbp
...
```

Sometimes when building one of the projects, Code::Blocks fails to finish the process with an error: `*** glibc detected *** codeblocks: corrupted double-linked list`. This has nothing to do with the build being failed, this is just a bug in codeblocks, see here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/codeblocks/+bug/764728
or here:
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16883.0

A workaround that I want to do is to parse the output of the command while it's still running, find the string "codeblocks: corrupted double-linked list", and kill the codeblocks to let the script build other projects and finish.

How can I do that?

Comment: One failed command from `codeblocks --build --target="release32" project1.cbp` will not cause further commands to be skipped, unless you have `set -e`, or running from `Makefile`..

Comment: It doesn't fail, it just prints an error and doesn't exit. Other commands are not executed, because this command is not finished yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hacky but will this work for you (`bash`)?

This is just to simulate the codeblocks binary (`./codeblocks`):

```
$ cat codeblocks
#!/bin/bash

num=$RANDOM
((num %= 2))

case "$num" in
        0)
                echo "codeblocks finished successfully: $*"
                exit 0
                ;;
        1)
                echo "*** glibc detected *** codeblocks: corrupted double-linked list" 1>&2
                while true; do
                        sleep 1
                done
                ;;
esac
```

This is the actual test script (`test.sh`):

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

run_codeblocks()
{
        until (
                subshell_pid=$BASHPID
                echo "trying to run 'codeblocks $*'"
                ./codeblocks "$@" 2>&1 | while read line; do
                        echo "[${line}]"
                        [[ ${line} == *"*** glibc detected ***"* ]] && kill $subshell_pid
                done
                return 0
        ); do
                :
        done
}

echo "running codeblocks ..."
run_codeblocks 1
run_codeblocks 2
run_codeblocks 3
echo "... done"
```

You wrap the call to `codeblocks` in a subshell, grep its output and if a line matches the error you stated kills the subshell. Basically exactly what you described.

```
$ ./test.sh
running codeblocks ...
trying to run 'codeblocks 1'
[codeblocks finished successfully: 1]
trying to run 'codeblocks 2'
[*** glibc detected *** codeblocks: corrupted double-linked list]
./test.sh: line 4: 29889 Terminated              ( subshell_pid=$BASHPID; echo "trying to run 'codeblocks $*'"; ./codeblocks "$@" 2>&1 | while read line; do
    echo "[${line}]"; [[ ${line} == *"*** glibc detected ***"* ]] && kill $subshell_pid; return 0;
done )
trying to run 'codeblocks 2'
[*** glibc detected *** codeblocks: corrupted double-linked list]
./test.sh: line 4: 29892 Terminated              ( subshell_pid=$BASHPID; echo "trying to run 'codeblocks $*'"; ./codeblocks "$@" 2>&1 | while read line; do
    echo "[${line}]"; [[ ${line} == *"*** glibc detected ***"* ]] && kill $subshell_pid; return 0;
done )
trying to run 'codeblocks 2'
[codeblocks finished successfully: 2]
trying to run 'codeblocks 3'
[*** glibc detected *** codeblocks: corrupted double-linked list]
./test.sh: line 4: 29903 Terminated              ( subshell_pid=$BASHPID; echo "trying to run 'codeblocks $*'"; ./codeblocks "$@" 2>&1 | while read line; do
    echo "[${line}]"; [[ ${line} == *"*** glibc detected ***"* ]] && kill $subshell_pid; return 0;
done )
trying to run 'codeblocks 3'
[codeblocks finished successfully: 3]
... done
```

Comment: This looks amazing and it almost worked! Almost... I don't know why, but some part of the output is handled by "while read line", while other part isn't. You made good thing by wrapping output into square brackets. Here how my output looks like: http://pastebin.com/nu0PRCqg

Comment: @user1113852 Wild guess, some output goes to stderr which is not caught there. Try redirecting codeblock's stderr to stdout (`2>&1`) before the reading pipe.

Comment: Tried to redirect like you suggested, still not caught. Also I realized that the error happens right after the call, not in the end, like I thought. Thus it is not enough just to kill codeblocks, I also need to repeat the failed command. Oh boy.

Comment: I have another idea how to solve my problem - create 2 subshells, 1st running codeblocks, and 2nd waiting 1 sec and checking if 1st subshell produced any output. If not, restart 1st subshell

Comment: @user1113852 I edited my post to reflect your need to rerun the command (the codeblocks testscript randomly "crashes" now). The subshell is wrapped in an `until` loop so it reruns when we kill it. Also added the stderr->stdout redirection. No idea why it does not work for you :-/